# Resolve: Unexpected token export?

Tags: javascript, webpack

How resolve this error: `Unexpected token export` ?

webpack config:

```js
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015'
      }]
    }
```

src file:

```js
import {PerspectiveCamera} from 'three/build/three.modules';
```

Comment: Please explain more what is your problem. What is the exact command you use to build your file ? Also, where is the `export` token in your file ? I don't see any so I doubt we can help you without knowing what's the origin of error.

Comment: Problem here: exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/   babel not watching this folders

Comment: @John What does that have to do with `export`?

Comment: No, with babel-loader. I am exclude: node_modules I think this